# Microservice - persisting to RDBMS & queue within a transaction

Tags: microservices, message-queue, messaging, vert.x, distributed-transactions

I have a REST service - all its requests are persisted to its own relational database. So far, good. But, there is also a small business functionality (email notification, sms alert) that should be run on the newly received/updated data. For this process to work on data in background, it requires some way to know about the persisted data - a message queue would fix the problem. Three common ways I see designing this,

1. The REST service inserts into the database, also, publish to the queue, too.

   - The problem here is, distributed transaction - combining different types within one transaction - relational database & the queue. Some tools may support, some may not.
2. As usual REST service persists only to its database. Additionally it also inserts the data into another table to which a scheduled job queries, publishes them to queue (from which the background job should start its work).

   - The problem I see is the scheduler - not reactive, batchprocessing, limited by the time slot, not realtime, slow and others.
3. The REST endpoint publishes the data directly to a `topic`. A consumer persists it to the database, whereas another process it in the background.

   - Something like eventsourcing. TMU, it is bit complex to implement as the number of services grow. Also, if the db is down, the persistent service would fail to save the data, however the background service (say, the emailer) would send email which is functionaly wrong. This may lead to inconsistency among the services, also functional.

I have also thought of reading database `transaction-logs`, but it seems more complex, requires tools to configurations to make it work, also, it seems right for data processing systems than for our use case.

What's your thought on this - did I miss anything? How do you manage such scenarios? What should be looked for? Thinking reactive, say `Vertx`?

Apologies if this looks very naive, but I have to ask.

Comment: I think you're mixing the approach and the implementation. The microservice should write to DB and publish that event to the queue, so stick with that good approach (option 1). I'm not sure what you mean in the details but I think you are asking which tools to use? You should take into account of FIFO, QoS, persistency, failure handling, and how it can have multiple consumers. AWS's SNS doesn't offer FIFO for example as of today, but I hear RabbitMQ is good.

Comment: Can you please elaborate the approach and implementation? Yes, I can use rabbitmq or activemq or even kafka to pass messages between processe, for that matter - but, given, the data is persisted to database when I publish the data to a queue, and should rollback when I couldn't.

Comment: If you can write to db but publishing fails, then that's another problem of handling failed publishing. I don't know your requirement but if you're returning 200 OK then it should persist to database and probably write to another table of failed publishing and it should retry publishing later.

Comment: Is that not redundant, then, to have logic across my services work this failed case. Also, I then design a scheduler that queries and pushes back to the queue. Sorry is this, again, is naive.

Comment: Assume the business need is, send sms (I can't loose any request). The background process prepares the sms payload from the request and fwd it to some external sms provider.

Comment: Then it would have to be re-published from that microservice, so it may seem redundant, but if you are doing this in a monolith, wouldn't you still be handling data logic for each case? Also, if you are creating another backup service to publish to, aren't you just going to create more points of failure, and still have to create the functionality in that microservice to republish if that backup fails?

Comment: I ain't proposing another service to handle the scenario, I am looking for practical ways to implement such cases.

Comment: you are right transaction-logs is bit hard to implement especially it really depends on the database and if you have to change databases you will have to change logic. Outbox pattern is another way. You basically save the transaction in  local database at the same time you would save the transaction in events (outbox) table that are to be published. A job will be picking up the events and mark them published once it pushes them to queue. Have a read https://microservices.io/patterns/data/transactional-outbox.html  .

Comment: Yes Imran, this approach generally requires a scheduler to pick the records from the message table and publish them to queue, something of 2nd approach. I'll add this specific details too to the question.

Comment: That's right. The reactive variation of this approach can be to publish the event right after DB transaction and mark it complete. The scheduler will only pick up those events that are failed to be published.

Comment: I'm interested to know the reactive way, you said, of doing this, if you can brief it.

Answer (score 1):

I think best approach is 2 with a CDC(change data capture) system like debezium.

See [https://microservices.io/patterns/data/transactional-outbox.html][1]

Comment: To add on this, Debezium has [explicit support](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/configuration/outbox-event-router.html) for the transactional outbox pattern. That way, no polling on the outbox table is needed, but new events from the outbox table can be efficiently extracted using CDC.

Answer (score 0):

I usually recommend option 3 if you don't need immediate read after write consistency. Background job should retry if the database record is still not updated by the message it processes.

Your post exemplifies why queues shouldn't be used for these types of scenarios. They are good for delivering analytical data or logs, but for task orchestration developers have to reinvent the wheel every time.

The much better approach is to use a task orchestration system like [Cadence Workflow](https://cadenceworkflow.io/) that eliminates issues you described and makes multi-service orchestration much simpler.

See [this presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=llmsBGKOuWI) that explains the Cadence programming model.